# Change the format from datetime into DDMMYYP10

Tags: date, sas, format

I tried a lot to convert the column LOADTIME (Format Datetime20.) into DDMMYYP10. But it doesn't work.

I tried it also just with PUT or INPUT and also DATEPART, but nothing works.

```
PROC SQL;
    UPDATE SERVER.VIEWTABLE V
    SET 'Load_Time__c'n = INPUT(PUT(V.LOAD_TIME, DATETIME20.), DDMMYYP10.);
QUIT;
```

The result of the code below is nothing, it runs thru but nothing is written in the field Load_Time__c.

Answer (score 0):

SAS stores DATETIME values as the number of seconds and DATE values are the number of days.  So before you change the display format attached to the variable you need to change the values stored in the variable.  You can use the DATEPART() function to convert a datetime value to a date value.

It is probably going to be easier to make a NEW dataset with the new variable instead of trying to modify the existing dataset.  Or possibly a new VIEW?

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  LOAD_TIME = datepart(LOAD_TIME);
  format LOAD_TIME ddmmyyp10.;
run;
```

Comment: New view is not possible. I make everytime a copy of the view at night because of the speed. After that I want to add some more column with the correct data types. I need to have a good basic for analysis.

Comment: So you want to run something like the data step in the answer to make a copy AND create the new variables.  Using SQL UPDATE command to modify the dataset after it is made is just going to double the work.